# B2C Validation of REST API

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

IN our forgot password flow, I want to do a REST API call to do a validation check on the account. We have a database that we need to do a check against.

During this process, the API will return a 200 or 400.

If its a 200, I want them to continue on with the orchestration of forgot password.

If it is a 400, instead of pulling them out of the flow and putting them back in the application, I would rather show them that there is a problem with their account and to contact our support or to register a new account.

However, no matter what the response, in my current code it is send them along in the orchestration step.

This is the orchestration step:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="GetMemberClaimsExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="MemberAccountHolderCollector" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

then this is my claims provider.

```
<ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>REST API to Check Member Status</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="MemberAccountHolderCollector">
          <DisplayName>Collect Member Info Technical Profile</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.register</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-CheckMemberAccountHolder" ContinueOnError="true"/>
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>

        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-CheckMemberAccountHolder">
          <DisplayName>Rest API call to Check Member status</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">{API}</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">QueryString</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="emailaddress"/>
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="emailaddress" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
```

The api.selfasserted.register is simply a template i created. I don't need to use it. I could just throw the error on the screen as anything, but I was just trying anything to get it to work.

Any help is appreciated here.

Edit:

Thank you for the advice, so i think i understand where your going.

I added a claim type

```
 <ClaimType Id="requireRegister">
    <DisplayName>requireRegster</DisplayName>
    <DataType>boolean</DataType>
    <UserInputType>Paragraph</UserInputType>
  </ClaimType>
```

The idea would be that I can do an output claim.

The problem is when i do this...

```
<TechnicalProfiles>
            <TechnicalProfile Id="MemberAccountHolderCollector">
              <DisplayName>Collect Member Info Technical Profile</DisplayName>
              <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
              <Metadata>
                <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.register</Item>
              </Metadata>
        <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="requireRegister" DefaultValue="true"/>
          </OutputClaims>
              <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-CheckMemberAccountHolder" ContinueOnError="true"/>
              </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            </TechnicalProfile>
```

It shows the page every time, which i don't want to do either...

Edit 2:

Our forgot password is done off this policy
[enter link description here][1]
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

in our policy when you click the forgot password button it invokes the subjourney

```
<SubJourneys>
    <SubJourney Id="PasswordReset" Type="Call">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <!-- Validate user's email address. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Show TOU-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertedConsentExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-PasswordResetConsent" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

There is a custom page to show our TOU consent, before they get there, I need the account to run through our validation before.

Edit 3:

Doing the code below skips the Email validation step in the forgot password policy.

```
<ClaimsProvider>
<DisplayName>REST API to Check Member</DisplayName>
<TechnicalProfiles>
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
<ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
<ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-CheckMemberAccount" ContinueOnError="false"/>
</ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>

<!--Not using anymore -->
<TechnicalProfile Id="MemberAccountHolderCollector">
<DisplayName>Collect Member Info Technical Profile</DisplayName>
<Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
<Metadata>
<Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.register</Item>
</Metadata>
<ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
<ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-CheckMemberAccount" ContinueOnError="false"/>
</ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>

<TechnicalProfile Id="REST-CheckMemberAccount">
<DisplayName>Rest API call to Check Member status</DisplayName>
<Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
<Metadata>
<Item Key="ServiceUrl">{API}</Item>
<Item Key="SendClaimsIn">QueryString</Item>
<Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
<Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
</Metadata>
<InputClaims>
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="emailaddress"/>
</InputClaims>
<OutputClaims>
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="emailaddress" />
</OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
</TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Comment: @Jas Suri - MSFT I made some edits taking your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This configuration, where there are no output claims as part of a selfAsserted technical profile, will cause B2C to skip this entire step.

You should be adding this as a validation technical profile on the previous step, where the user enters and validates their email. As follows:

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
          <DisplayName>Reset password using email address</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Your account has been locked. Contact your support person to unlock it, then try again.</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="requireRegister" DefaultValue="true"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="MemberAccountHolderCollector" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Remove `MemberAccountHolderCollector` technical profile entirely. And any reference to that from your User Journey.

Now after the user validates their email, and submits the page, the REST API will be called. If it returns an error, it is displayed on the same screen where the user validated their email.

You must return a HTTP 409 conflict with proper error JSON payload for it to be displayed on the screen.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#returning-validation-error-message

Comment: Ok, im kinda confused at what you mean where they are validating their email... In the password reset flow you are sent a validation code, after the validation code you move to step 2 in the orchestration step correct? Where am I putting this exactly? Weare not going to use Javascript.

Comment: Also im not opposed to doing a different configuration. I just don't want the user to leave the application if the API returns another other than 200.

Comment: I made some edits taking your suggestions.

Comment: I am trying various different things to your suggestion. I cant seem to get it to work. Are you suggest not taking to them the template page and instead show the error on the screen? I tried that the first go around with this and I could not get it to work.

Comment: Sorry one last thing as I am still new to this, and this is my first validation step, do I need ADD in an orchestration step or can this all be done with 1 step, because that's what I am doing now.

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look at that approach first.

Comment: ok, I understand what your doing, i am using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy for my forgot password, so that flow does not exist for me.

Comment: Its the same, it still uses `LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress`.

Comment: ok, i just made the edit in my first post... so your saying maybe a good approach would be to be copy LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress out of base and then make this custom one?

Comment: That or, better is override it in extension file:  `<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="MemberAccountHolderCollector" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237703/discussion-between-bnd10706-and-jas-suri-msft).

Comment: So i added a bunch of information to chat, but i also edited my response above.

Comment: OK, so i copied what you had listed. If the <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="MemberAccountHolderCollector" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles> is included in this flow, it does not run the email validation step.

Comment: OK I want to let you know this worked. The solution was to remove the output claim in the API.